# Display a message "Users loading" when my async method is retrieving user data from api

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a method to call an api and get the users. When I have this api call in an async method, I want to display a message "Users are loading.." until users are retrieved and displayed in my form.

need to create a task which is looking for 'users' and displays a message until users get some data.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void ButtonLoadEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbStatus.Text = "Wait it is Loading... ";
    Loading();
}

private async Task Loading()
{
    await Task.Delay(100);             //wait until delay finish
    lbStatus.Text = "It is finished";  //then notify
}
```

Comment: Thank you Zaur. But I dont want to add delay. It has to display the message until the api gives back users. I want to create the task which will look for 'users' variable. until it is null, display the message and once it gets the data, display the users list.

Comment: You could instead make `ButtonLoadEvent_Click` async and `await  Loading();`, setting a label's text after. This, of couse, if the OP has a WinForms app. The question itself doesn't suggest this, though. You should ask the OP what *display a message* means, in practice. Also, in what context this code is run.

Comment: (But I don't want to add delay)  instead of delay you should write your own business logic.